# Efficiently create edgelist from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some publication data I want to do co-authorship analysis on. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Author     Title     Pub_date     City
John A.    Paper 1   2020-01-01   Boston
Joan B.    Paper 1   2020-01-01   Boston
Jeff C.    Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Joan B.    Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Jose D.    Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
```

I want to create an unweighted, undirected edgelist that retains the publication data as edge attributes like this:

```
Node1    Node2       Title     Pub_date     City
John A.  Joan B.     Paper 1   2020-01-01   Boston
Joan B.  John A.     Paper 1   2020-01-01   Boston
Jeff C.  Joan B.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Jeff C.  Jose D.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Joan B.  Jeff C.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Joan B.  Jose D.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Jose D.  Jeff C.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
Jose D.  Joan B.     Paper 2   2020-02-01   Chicago
```

I can get to the basic idea with this:

`edgelist = pd.merge(left=df, right=df, how='outer', on='Title')`

But then I have to do a lot of fixing to drop duplicate columns, do renames, and get rid of rows that don't have coauthors. It seems inefficient to me. I don't know how scalable an approach this is either when the dataset is very large or when there are a lot of columns.

Would really appreciate some suggestions for improvement.

Comment: What if you have more than two coauthors?

Comment: Yes - I often will/do. A subset of authors should have an edge between each author. I will update the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Thanks for all the ideas!

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["John A.",    "Paper 1",   "2020-01-01",   "Boston"],
["Joan B." ,   "Paper 1",   "2020-01-01",   "Boston"],
["Jeff C." ,   "Paper 2" ,  "2020-02-01" ,  "Chicago"],
["Joan B." ,   "Paper 2" ,  "2020-02-01" ,  "Chicago"],
["Jose D." ,   "Paper 2" ,  "2020-02-01" ,  "Chicago"]],
columns=["Author", "Title", "Pub_date", "City"])
```

My solution was to make a function where I can specify the column with the node id, and column(s) with the shared attributes to fold the network by so I don't have to change a bunch of column names for different data.

```
def df_to_folded_edgelist(df, node_id_col='node_id', fold_id_cols=['fold_attribute']):
        
    df_list = []
    df_orig = df.copy()
    
    #group the node ids by the fold attribute column(s)

    for i, g in df.groupby(fold_id_cols)[node_id_col]:
        
        # get the pairwise combinations for each group
        for u, v in itertools.combinations(g, 2):

            # add the pair and the first index from that group to a list

            df_list.append([u, v, g.first_valid_index()])


    #convert to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['node_1', 'node_2', 'orig_index']) 
    
    #merge the original data so each edge now has all the other columns        
    edgelist = df.merge(df_orig, how='left', left_on='orig_index', right_index=True)

    #drop the unnecessary columns
    edgelist.drop(columns=['orig_index', node_id_col], inplace=True)
        
    return edgelist
```

I'm not sure how fast this will be on larger datasets, but I think it's reusable for any new data I get, and I only have to know which columns contain my node ids and which my folding attributes.

Answer (score 0):

it is the data you provided:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([["John A.",    "Paper 1",   "2020-01-01",   "Boston"],
["Joan B." ,   "Paper 1",   "2020-01-01",   "Boston"],
["Jeff C." ,   "Paper 2" ,  "2020-02-01" ,  "Chicago"],
["Joan B." ,   "Paper 2" ,  "2020-02-01" ,  "Chicago"]],
columns=["Author", "Title", "Pub_date", "City"])
```

it is the solution:

```
first = data.groupby(by=["Title", "Pub_date", "City"]).first().reset_index().rename(columns={"Author": "Node1"})
last = data.groupby(by=["Title", "Pub_date", "City"]).last().reset_index().rename(columns={"Author": "Node2"})
edgelist = pd.merge(first, last, how='left', on=["Title", "Pub_date", "City"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to create a list of authors per publication.  You can expand those lists into new columns using `pd.Series` then rename them and concatenate back.  This should work fine for any number of authors sharing the same publication.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Author': {0: 'John A.', 1: 'Joan B.', 2: 'Jeff C.', 3: 'Joan B.'},
 'Title': {0: 'Paper 1', 1: 'Paper 1', 2: 'Paper 2', 3: 'Paper 2'},
 'Pub_date': {0: '2020-01-01',
  1: '2020-01-01',
  2: '2020-02-01',
  3: '2020-02-01'},
 'City': {0: 'Boston', 1: 'Boston', 2: 'Chicago', 3: 'Chicago'}})


df = df.groupby(['Title','Pub_date','City'])['Author'].apply(list).reset_index()

a = df.Author.apply(pd.Series)
a.columns = [f'Node{x+1}' for x in a.columns]

df = pd.concat([df,a],axis=1)

df.drop(columns='Author', inplace=True)
```